# KeyError 250000 when trying to create an image dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, google-colaboratory, resnet

I'm trying to create an image dataset on Colab and I'm getting the following error:

```
Item no.: 1 --> Item name = jaguar
Evaluating...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-9097d8d70946> in <module>()
     19         }   #creating list of arguments
     20 response  = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()   #class instantiation
---> 21 response.download(arguments)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google_images_download/google_images_download.py in build_url_parameters(self, arguments)
    405         for key, value in params.items():
    406             if value[0] is not None:
--> 407                 ext_param = value[1][value[0]]
    408                 # counter will tell if it is first param added or not
    409                 if counter == 0:

KeyError: 250000
```

This is my code:

```
from google_images_download import google_images_download 

keyws   = "jaguar"
limit   = 1000
chromedriver = chromedriver_path
offset  = None
color_type  = None
size    = 500*500
usage_rights    = 'labeled-for-reuse'

arguments = {
        "keywords" : keyws,
        "limit" :limit,
        "chromedriver":chromedriver,
        "offset" : offset,
        "color_type" : color_type,
        "size" : size,
        "usage_rights" : usage_rights
        }
response  = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()
response.download(arguments)
```

The error is pointing to my `response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()` line.  I tried looking up the error but couldn't find anything about it.  This is my first time coming across this error so I really don't know why my code is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see in the code for over at [github](https://github.com/hardikvasa/google-images-download/blob/0d2bf8f17b5a8806d90df7258e7a172aa0cb7963/google_images_download/google_images_download.py#L407) is that the size parameter does not take integers. It takes categorical values described in this [page](https://google-images-download.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arguments.html)

> Possible values:
>
> large, medium, icon, >400*300, >640*480, >800*600, 1024*768, >2MP, >4MP, >6MP, >8MP, >10MP, >12MP, >15MP, >20MP, >40MP, >70MP

Comment: That's what I have, no?

Comment: You have size as `size    = 500*500` right? and that where the key error is coming for 250000

Comment: So how should I change my input?  Just 500?

Comment: No u need to have it to be one of the above values, eg. try `size = "large"` and it'll work

Comment: Yea but large is a range of values.  I need all my images to be of the same size.

Comment: Hm, then based on the documentation, you are looking for the `exact_size = (500,500)` argument!